# Aptana "The selection cannot be launched, and there are no recent launches."

Tags: aptana

Each time I click the "Run as" button, I get the following message.

"The selection cannot be launched, and there are no recent launches."

If I select the pull down arrow near the "Run as" button, and select the New configuration option (this is the configuration I setup to launch using localhost)... it works.  But why doesn't the "Run as" button default to this?

Or better yet, how do I make sure the "Run as" button will default to this?

** UPDATE **

I solved the problem.. see my answer below.

Comment: Sometimes this can be fixed by restarting eclipse.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Go into the preferences under Run/Debug > Launching

There's a section called "Launch Operation" and I needed to select:

Launch the selected resource or active editor. If no launchable: Launch the previously launched application.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution for that:

If you have imported project from local file system then go to the respective folder -> right click on that -> Promote to project -> Select a project type (Mine was Ruby-Primary) -> Finish.

Should work. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to Aptana and started a new file, say a .py file, MAKE SURE you also start a Project. You probably haven't started a project yet, so Aptana has no clue what to do with the file you are running. If you create a project and make it a Python project, NOW Aptana knows what to do with your new file and will run it correctly.