# Aptana Studio: "The selection cannot be launched, and there are no recent launches."

Tags: aptana

Even single time I try to setup a new project, this error pops up. I can't remember how I fixed it the first time.

Conveniently, this question has [already been answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8674453/aptana-the-selection-cannot-be-launched-and-there-are-no-recent-launches).

"Go into the preferences under Run/Debug > Launching

There's a section called "Launch Operation" and I needed to select:

Launch the selected resource or active editor. If no launchable: Launch the previously launched application."

However, I cannot find the directory Run/Debug > Launching. My question is: **Where do I find it on newer versions of Aptana?**

Comment: I have the same exact question - can't find Run/Debug > Launching

Comment: @user3546086 sorry I haven't found an answer. I just gave up and am now writing all my programs in sublime and running them in my terminal. Apparently that's the norm anyway.

Comment: I'm also trying to switch to Sublime - but how do you open / launch the file in Chrome? I'm also thinking the problem was because it was an xml file. I've never had a problem launching HTML, CSS, or JS, but now with an XML file nothing's happening - maybe Aptana doesn't support XML?

Answer (score 0):

Launching is under Preferences -> Run/Debug, and it has two options "Default Launchers" and "Launch Configurations" but I can't find the "Launch Operation" that he is talking about. Nothing comes up in the windows when I go into "Default Launchers" and Changing the options in "Launch Configurations" did not seem to help either. I am having the exact same issue and have no launch history, so I am not even sure how I could use a previous launcher if none are there.
Also, when I attempt to "Run As" I only get "PHP Script" and "PHP Server" as the options.