# Aptana: The selection cannot be launched and there are no recent launches

Tags: python, aptana

This question has been asked [and answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8674453/aptana-the-selection-cannot-be-launched-and-there-are-no-recent-launches) before but I'm still having a problem.

I found the settings under Preferences and selected "Launch the selected resource or active editor. If no launchable:" and "Launch the previously launched application". However, now when I try to run it just repeats the last program instead of the one I'm currently working on.

Here is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWibA.png) of the problem. Note that the program executed is totally different than the one I'm trying to run.

EDIT: I figured it out, see my answer below.

Comment: Disclaimer: I am not familiar with Aptana.  That said, it appears (from the green gutter annotation) the contents of "Mutliples_of_3_and_5" is all new and (from the asterisk against the file name) that "Multiples_of_3_and_5" hasn't been saved.
Could that be the reason it is not launchable?

Comment: That's wasn't it, but thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I needed to end my file names with .py

In this specific case: Mutliples_of_3_and_5.py